# JS returning No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some unusual problems with my React app about Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I had problems like this with login/register system and I fixed it (obviously not). Now I have problems with getting user information. In the same file where I have my login, register I have a function to grab user info, when I console.log it's giving me  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with Request, Method: OPTIONS, Status Code: 403 Forbidden, and my code look like this.

```
export const getProfile = () => {
    return axios
        .get('api/user', {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}` }
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            return response.data
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}
```

I'm using Laravel API, I have a function for handling CORS, I had difficulties with login/register and it was the same problem, I fixed it and CORS is obviously not handling well or there is something wrong?
When I try in Postman everything works fine.

This is how login form looks like.

```
export const userSignIn = ({email, password}) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: FETCH_START});
    axios.post('api/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      }
    ).then(response => {
     if (response.data.success) {
        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
        axios.defaults.headers.common['access-token'] = "Bearer " + response.data.token;
        dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS});
        dispatch({type: USER_TOKEN_SET, payload: response.data.token});
      } else {
        dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: response.data.message});
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error.message});
      console.log("Error****:", error.message);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: CORS is a issue that has to be solved from the server side by adding few headers to the response API and handling the `OPTIONS` request. Search for an Laravel CORS middleware and add it to your codebase for easier approach.

Comment: Yes, I have cors installed on my laravel app, works fine with other functions

Answer (score 0):

Even if I install chrome extension to block CORS, still same error, just there is not message that is blocked by cors because of headers.

Answer (score -1):

first of all,
You are trying to get a token from local storage, you should write like this:

```
localStorage.getItem('token')//make sure 'token' is the name you saved in local storage
```

try adding the following code in the headers along with "Authorization" and check if it works:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
```

if it does not work, add more in headers

```
 headers: { "X-Custom-Header": "foobar", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(token)}` },
```

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header has to come from the server in the response, not the client in the request.

Comment: it works at least when I was working with backend developers.

Comment: This doesn't work. I put the login form in post maybe it could help  to see what is the problem :)

Comment: It sounds like you need to whitelist the connection to your API on the server side to allow connections from whatever port/domain your UI is running on.